# How can I open a Java console output window for Applet debugging in a browser (windows)?

Tags: java, applet, log4j

I have firefox 11 or the windows XP version of IE -

and the browser has jre6
and I have a 6 month old jsdk but the browser doesn't use that for runtime.

nice if log window had history and a scrollbar if there are a lot of prints.
I'm using log4j to do the prints.

Thanks.

Comment: Your OS is 64 or 32-bit? The same question for jre6. Do you have some java icons in system tray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly, I think what you are looking for is the 'Java Console'. Here is some info about how to find it and how to enable if it is disabled: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Comment: Good find.  OTOH that does not work for Windows 7.  To be honest, I can't figure how to access the JCP in Windows 7 short of the advice in my answer.

Comment: Works fine on my Windows 7 machine. You should have the Java Control panel in the Windows Control panel on Windows 7. You may need to select 'large icons' instead of the default category view to see it.

Comment: OK - I had the Control Panel set to Category (which I find to be confusing & irritating interface).  But there is still nothing in the Large Icons view that so much as starts with 'J' (it goes Internet Options then Keyboard).  Typing 'J' produces that helpful little 'ding' sound.  I conclude from this that *this machine* has a more broken Java set-up than I'd thought (was having niggling problems but was ignoring them).  Thanks for the info. & making me look further into it.  I'd +1, but I did that before. :)

Comment: Also, just booted the Netbook (running Windows 7) & confirmed your steps, except for 2 minor things.  1) Point 2 of the linked list 'Select **Settings'** is no longer necessary, Win. 7 has the Control Panel listed directly in the start menu. 2) Here the launch button for the JCP is actually titled 'Java' in the Control Panel.  ..Anyway, I'll slink away now & try to sort my desktop machine, rather than further pollute this thread with the problems of my broken development environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the [Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp).
2. (Close the application viewer that opens on top of it.)
3. ..follow the advice at the link shown by Mathias.

The reason for the difference in the opening steps is that the early part of that advice is no longer valid in Windows 7.  The steps 1) & 2) outlined above, will get you to the Java Control Panel in XP, Vista & 7.