# Converting Java applet into <object>

Tags: java, html, object, applet

I recently updated my Java to the most up to date version and this caused an applet that I work with to not run correctly.  I have changed the security parameters for Java through the Control Panel to the lowest possible settings but my applet still does not run. Here is what my applet looked like:

```
<HTML>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="#003333">

 <p>
 <APPLET name=IpixViewer code=IpixViewer.class archive="IpixViewer.jar" width=450      height=450>
<PARAM NAME="url" VALUE="209_a_CHEM.ipx">
 </APPLET>
 </p>

 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

I tried to use the HTML  tag as a work around but this also is failing. Here is that code:

```
<HTML>
<body>
<p>
<object type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" name="IpixViewer" id="ipixviewer"  style="width:450px;height:450px" >
<param name="code" value="IpixViewer.class" >
<param name="archive" value="IpixViewer.jar" >
<param name="codebase" value="Z:\filepath\">
<param name="url" value="205_a_CHEM.ipx" >

</object>
</p>
</body>
</HTML>
```

I think the issue is when I try to pass the url parameter into the applet but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `CODEBASE` is used to add a path to the jar file, e.g.:

```
CODEBASE="./my_path_to_jar"
```

So to draw a complete picture, this is a working example:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <APPLET NAME="IpixViewer"
            CODE="IpixViewer.class" 
            CODEBASE="."
            ARCHIVE="IpixViewer.jar" 
            WIDTH="320" HEIGH="240" >
    <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="image.ipx">
  </APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This HTML file (`ipix.html`), the jar file `IpixViewer.jar` and the image `image.ipx` are all placed in the same folder.

As it is not easily possible to start an applet from a local hard disk, I used a tool called [HFS](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) to access the website. For this just start the program, drop the files on it and type `http://127.0.0.1/ipix.html`.

If this doesn't help you can [open a Java console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833183/how-can-i-open-a-java-console-output-window-for-applet-debugging-in-a-browser-w) in order to retrieve further information.

Comment: This is what my Java console shows:
\Java version: 1.7.0_25
JVM version: 23.25-b01
JVM vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java specification name: Java Platform API Specification
Java specification vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java specification version: 1.7
OS architecture: x86
OS name: Windows 7
OS version: 6.1
Browser: Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1)

Loading IPIX: 'null'...
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at IpixViewer.a(IpixViewer.java)
 at IpixViewer.f(IpixViewer.java)
 at IpixViewer.run(IpixViewer.java)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Ok, I was slightly on a wrong track. Just made a small test and it worked quite well. Note that it is not possible to start from a folder directly.

Comment: In particular, the codebase parameter needs to be a URI, not a file path.  `Z:\filepath\⁠` is not a valid URI, but `file:///Z:/filepath/` is.  A URI always contains forward slashes, on every operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Give the java deployment toolkit a try. It will work great and handles cross browser compatibility.

http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/deployment_toolkit.xml